# Is it possible to automatically lock the doors when my Santa Fe is shifted from park?

Tags: locks, wiring, hyundai

I'm working on a 2002 Hyundai Santa Fe. I'd like to get the doors to lock when the vehicle is shifted from park, and unlock when the vehicle is shifted to park. There is an indicator on the dash that displays the current status of the transmission, so there must be signal wiring somewhere.

I've located the the power lock wire (Yellow wire in 22 pin white plug, in drivers kick panel) and the power unlock wire (White/Black wire in 22 pin white plug, in driver kick panel), but I'm not sure where the wiring that signals the transmissions status is located or the wire colors.  I'm also not sure how the signaling wires are powered, so I don't know if a simple jumper will accomplish the task, or if it will require a custom control circuit.

Is it possible to get the doors to lock when the vehicle is shifted from park, and unlock when the vehicle is shifted to park?

---

## Update

After doing a bit of research online, it seemed that this may have been a dealer programmed feature. However, after sending an email to Hyundai customer support, it appears this "feature" is not included in this model year vehicle.  Hyundai customer support directed me to contact my local dealer, though I'm guessing the dealer would simply try to sell me a new vehicle that actually has this feature.

Comment: I kinda hope this is one you plan on "asking and answering." You're probably in a better position to answer it than anyone else, and it seems like you're more than half way there!

Comment: Since it's not possible from the factory, are you leaving this unanswered as a way of asking for a custom solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a hold of the wiring diagrams for your car you could probably figure it out.

Both the transmission gear wiring and lock and unlock likely go to the Smart Junction Control Box (SJB) if you can pull the wiring diagram for that (It will have ton of stuff though) you can trace where the gear indicator wiring comes from and whether it will be powered or grounded on the park.

You could then possibly set up a couple relays so that when that wire becomes either powered or grounded you ground the lead to tell the SJB to unlock / lock the doors.

This is similar to in my car which did not have a trunk release button I simply wired one in by splicing my button to the SJB lead that controls the trunk.

Yours will be trickier to implement but a similar idea.